# Creating a for loop of pie charts

Tags: python, for-loop, data-science

I am trying to create a for loop which loops over all of teh data values of my pandas dataframe and creates a pie chart with fast and flow charging stations as hue for each year. It should also have the percentage of the total charging stations for each year.

```
    region  powertrain  year    value
38  Australia   Publicly available fast 2017    40.0
39  Australia   Publicly available slow 2017    440.0
44  Australia   Publicly available fast 2018    61.0
45  Australia   Publicly available slow 2018    670.0
54  Australia   Publicly available fast 2019    250.0
55  Australia   Publicly available slow 2019    1700.0
60  Australia   Publicly available fast 2020    350.0
61  Australia   Publicly available slow 2020    2000.0
70  Australia   Publicly available fast 2021    350.0
73  Australia   Publicly available slow 2021    2000.0
```

Above is my data frame known as ev_aus

```
ev_aus.head(10)
for i in ev_aus['year'].value_counts():
    i.plot.pie(y='Powertrain', figsize = (5, 5), title = 'PowerTrain')

# p = ev_aus['powertrain'].value_counts()
# p.plot.pie(y='Powertrain', figsize = (5, 5), title = 'PowerTrain')
```

Here is what I have tried so far any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

since you have all the data already in a dataframe, you dont need a `for loop`.

One can use just `pandas` and the `matplotlib` modules to achieve such a result.

You can achieve what you want like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the dataframe
data = {'region': ['Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia'],
        'powertrain': ['Publicly available fast', 'Publicly available slow', 'Publicly available fast', 'Publicly available slow', 'Publicly available fast', 'Publicly available slow', 'Publicly available fast', 'Publicly available slow', 'Publicly available fast', 'Publicly available slow'],
        'year': [2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021],
        'value': [40.0, 440.0, 61.0, 670.0, 250.0, 1700.0, 350.0, 2000.0, 350.0, 2000.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group the data by powertrain and sum the values
grouped = df.groupby('powertrain').sum()

# Create the pie chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pie(grouped['value'], labels=grouped.index, autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax.set_title('Values by Powertrain')

plt.show()
```

and the result looks like this:

[image]